# Load JavaScript file in qwebview

Tags: javascript, qt, qwebview

If I launch my HTML page in a browser it's ok but it doesn't work in qt with qwebview. Any problem with browser.

My HTML:

```
<script src="{% static "js/myjavascript.js"%}"></script>
```

MY QT :

```
QWebView * myview = new QWebView(this);
myview->load("http://127.0.0.1/main.html");
```

How to declare my JavaScript file in MY qt?

Comment: have you tried single quotes? <script src="{% static 'js/myjavascript.js'%}"></script>

Comment: My problem is in my QT and qwebview, html is ok in browser

Comment: Is't local js file?

Comment: `{% static " some.js "%}` is not standard.